# Regex pattern extract string between curly braces and exclude curly braces

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

```
$str='\add[sometext]{\begin{equation}\label{eqn:3}
f_{1} =
\begin{cases}}
\beta_{1} + \beta_{2}f_{2} & f_{2}\leq \gamma\\
\beta_{1} + \beta_{2}\gamma + \beta_{4}(f_{2}-\gamma) & f_{2} >\gamma
\end{cases}sdsdssd,
\end{equation}}
 it may have some extra code here with {}
 \end{equation}}'
```

I need to extract the string between `\add[sometext]{` and `}`(i.e.till \add tag end curly braces)The string between `\add[sometext]{` and `}` may varies so I can't specify these string in regex pattern I should only consider starting and ending curly braces of `\add[sometext]`

Expected output:

```
\begin{equation}\label{eqn:3}
    f_{1} =
    \begin{cases}
    \beta_{1} + \beta_{2}f_{2} & f_{2}\leq \gamma\\
    \beta_{1} + \beta_{2}\gamma + \beta_{4}(f_{2}-\gamma) & f_{2} >\gamma
    \end{cases}sdsdssd,
    \end{equation}
```

I tried:

`$str=preg_replace('/\\\\add\s*\[\s*\w*\]\s*{(.*?)}/s,$1,$match)`

I don't know how to get related curly braces (i.e.`\add tag start { till end }`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got a regex for my requirement.

`$str = preg_replace('/\\\\add\s*\[.*]\s*{(.*?)\\\\end{(.[^\s]*?)}}/s', "$1\\end{\$2}", $str);`

[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/vT6qQ3/8)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple regex like this:

```
\{([\s\S]*)\}
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/vT6qQ3/1)**

[image]

**Match information**

```
MATCH 1
1.  [21-226]    `\begin{equation}\label{eqn:3}
f_{1} =
\begin{cases}}
\beta_{1} + \beta_{2}f_{2} & f_{2}\leq \gamma\\
\beta_{1} + \beta_{2}\gamma + \beta_{4}(f_{2}-\gamma) & f_{2} >\gamma
\end{cases}sdsdssd,
\end{equation}`
```

As you can see in the match information, the captured content is what you need.

The idea behind this regex is

```
\{([\s\S]*)\}
      ^--- Capture everything in a greedy way from the first `{` to the last `}`
```

But also you can do the same thing if you use the `s` flag (single line):

```
(?s)\{(.*)\} --> using inline `s` flag
    \{(.*)\} --> using external `s` flag
```

For PHP code you can have:

```
$re = "@\\{(.*)\\}@s"; 
$str = "\$str='\add[sometext]{\begin{equation}\label{eqn:3}\nf_{1} =\n\begin{cases}}\n\beta_{1} + \beta_{2}f_{2} & f_{2}\leq \gamma\\\n\beta_{1} + \beta_{2}\gamma + \beta_{4}(f_{2}-\gamma) & f_{2} >\gamma\n\end{cases}sdsdssd,\n\end{equation}}'"; 

preg_match($re, $str, $matches);
```

**Update:**

You can use this regex for your updated comments in the question:

```
\{([\s\S]*equation\})\}
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/vT6qQ3/4)**

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It doesn't solve the problem.  If  string is `\add[sometext]{\begin{equation}\label{eqn:3}
f_{1} =
\begin{cases}
\beta_{1} + \beta_{2}f_{2} & f_{2}\leq \gamma\\
\beta_{1} + \beta_{2}\gamma + \beta_{4}(f_{2}-\gamma) & f_{2} >\gamma
\end{cases}sdsdssd,
\end{equation}} and some extra code here}} or }`  it captures till the last curly braces. I need till `\add tag starting { to ending }`

Comment: @Vidhya if you look at the screenshot, the green highlight you can see that it captures your expected output

Comment: I have updated the post. The string might be having many curly braces. So that I need to get only `\add tag related curly braces`

Comment: @Vidhya use this regex instead **[working demo](https://regex101.com/r/vT6qQ3/4)**

Comment: Actually for my post this would be correct solution. My aim is to get string between related curly braces why because `equation}` may varies. it might be `align}` as such so I can't to specify `equation` string and if I have another `equation}` in my string it will capture that too. So that Can you tell me how to get starting curly braces of `\add[]`tag and ending curly braces only then these limitations can be avoided

Answer (score 1):

how about this:

```
$str='\add[sometext]{\begin{equation}\label{eqn:3}
f_{1} =
\begin{cases}
\beta_{1} + \beta_{2}f_{2} & f_{2}\leq \gamma\\
\beta_{1} + \beta_{2}\gamma + \beta_{4}(f_{2}-\gamma) & f_{2} >\gamma
\end{cases}sdsdssd,
\end{equation}}';

$str= preg_match('/\\\\add\s*\[\s*\w*\]\s*{(.*?)}$/s',$str,$match);

var_dump($match[1]);
```

Comment: It might not be the end of the string.. Extra string may continues after that.